# I just planted a Paperwhite bulb and I broke the roots. Will it still grow?

Tags: plant-health, bulbs, roots

I planted it, indoors, about 2 days ago. I rotated it because I thought it was leaning. Then I heard a snap and realized i'd broken the roots. I didn't think roots would have already sprouted :(. Did I kill it? Or will it re-root itself??

Answer (score 3):

It'll probably grow new ones. I planted mine a week ago and they're nearly blooming!
I've had our native ones indoors for months, trying to for them and the paperwhites have done more in a week than those others have in 2 months! It might be too hot inside for the native ones, paperwhites are from the Med so can tolerate the heat better I guess.